# What is the meaning of this broadcast?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham City*, you can use the Cryptographic Sequencer to decode various broadcasts.

At the approximate position of 637 on the x-axis, and 472 on the y-axis is a person reading off a series of numbers, similar to a [number station](http://www.damninteresting.com/number-stations/). When you try to decode the broadcast on the sequencer, it doesn't do anything.

Has anyone discovered what these numbers mean? The number sequence is (hopefully I wrote it down right):

9-23-9-12-12-18-5-20-21-18-14-2-1-20-13-1-14

Comment: Theres 3 number stations in total

Comment: I reckon it might be [an oblique *Lost* reference too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_numbers#The_numbers), given that there are *Lost* references in a Joker speech and one bit of random thug dialogue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). a = 1, b = 2, etc.

> iwillreturnbatman

or

> I will return Batman

I just listened to it, and the voice is familiar, put I can't put it to a character (not the Riddler, he wants you to know the puzzle is his).

Comment: Yeah, should have figured this one out myself. I can't place the voice either, I'm interested to see how it plays out.

Comment: I tried that cipher on a whim, figuring that the developers would go for something that would _not_ tax the worlds greatest detective.

Comment: I think that its Anarky talking but if its not him it could be Brainiac because oracle was in this game instead of bat girl

Comment: @kevin Personally I don't think it is Anarky. The voice sounds too old, and I think Braniac is right out as he is a Superman villain.

Comment: It sounds like a mans voice but what if its Harley disguising her voice?

Comment: @sam I doubt that very much as this can be heard anytime in Story.

Comment: @Doozer According to wikipedia, it's [Calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_%28comics%29#Video_Games). I found this on a whim looking up the character after being amused by listening to him in DCUO.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: It's not Calculator; see my answer.

Answer (score 39):

It's a [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher):  A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26.

Decoded, it reads *(station 675-525)*:

> I WILL RETURN BATMAN

---

There are also two other messages that you do no get until later in the game.  One of them is *(station 500-900)*:

> 5 15 9 7 21 18 18 14 3 5 24 15 12 7 22 3 10 5 15 9 22 3 8 25 26 15 16 25 10 15 17 25

This one is still a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher, but with a slightly different code:  A=3, B=2, C=1, D=26, E=25, ..., Y=5, Z=4.

When finally decoded, it reads

> YOU WILL PAY FOR WHAT YOU HAVE DONE TO ME

---

The last one is *(station 200-500 - you have to beat the game first??)*

> 3 20 26 18 26 16 24 1 11 4 24 9 3 8 5 2 12 18 6 16 7 11 3 10 17 5 13 4 21 8

Unfortunately, this one doesn't seem to be a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher - no matter what substitutions we use, we get gibberish:

> CTZRZPXAKDXICHEBLRFPGKCJQEMDUH

There are rumors circulating (originating, it appears, with IGN) that when decoded, this reads  *"I am your darkest nightmare dark knight.  Gotham city waits for his savior."*  However, this is clearly wrong - there are way too many letters!

Fortunately, not too long ago [one of the super-sleuths on Batman: Arkham City forums decoded it](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/6627-HIdden-Cryptographic-Sequencer-Message/page4):

> If you treat it as a [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) using the key SCARECROW, then [do atbash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash), the message comes out to:
>  FEAR WILL TEAR GOTHAM CITY TO SHREDS
>  Therefore, it is pretty obvious **the messages are being sent by Scarecrow**.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple code. Think 1=A, 2=B, etc.

Comment: You are the only one who wrote `1=A, 2=B  etc.`  other wrote `A=1, B=2 ETC` Oh you flooded this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000905/order-of-items-being-compared